# Rails Active Record Query - multiple values condition (AND instead of OR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using the [acts_as_taggable_on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) in a Rails 4.1 app. I am using a scope to search based on a tag or multiple tags. When multiple tags are given as the param I want the search to return only tagged items that contain ALL tags. Currently the scope I has returns tagged items that contain at least one of the tags (tag_a OR tag_b OR tag_c). I want a scope that instead is an AND condition (tag_a AND tag_b AND tag_c).

**Example**

```
document_a_tags = ['programming', 'ruby']
document_b_tags = ['programming', 'python']

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
  scope :with_fields, proc { |fields|
    if fields.reject!(&:empty?).present?
      joins(documents: [{ taggings: :tag }]).where(tags: { slug: fields })
    end
  }
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Currently, if the search params include `programming` and `ruby` both document_a and document_b will be returned. What I want is a scope where if the search params include `programming` and `ruby` only document_a will be returned.

Comment: Did you try: `tagged_with`? e.g.: `Item.joins(documents: [{ taggings: :tag }]).tagged_with(fields)`?

Comment: @User089247 thanks for your suggestion. That gives me an error though as the tags are on the Document model, not the User model: `NoMethodError (undefined method `tagged_with' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation`. Is there a way to adjust the query you suggested to account for this?

Comment: @diask2: I didn't write it as `User...` it was `Item..` however, one must understand the difference between an example and actual code, and use the idea to make the solution work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way mysql works I would think this is hard to accomplish in a single active record query.

The join adds one row for each tag that is connected to your entry and conditions are only applied to one row at the time. That is, a row can't be excluded by a condition saying that certain other rows in your result.

I think it might be possible to write some complex recursive query adding an undetermined number of columns to the result and applying the conditions on them. But I think it will be much easier and more performant to simply use your current scope and then in ruby code discard entries without all tags.

edit:
This might be done in the gem you are using. Look at:

```
User.tagged_with(["awesome", "cool"], :match_all => true)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this scope is on the User model, but it is the Document model (User has_many :documents) that has tags. So if I try tagged_with I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'tagged_with' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:`

Comment: It was just an example copied from their documentation. It has to be adjusted to your settings

Comment: Thank you, that was nice of you to say.